# C# Interface too rigid

Tags: c#, interface, design-patterns, oop

I'm working with some legacy code and have this existing interface:

```
public interface IProcess
{
    IDTO Process(IDTO request);
}
```

There is then a factory with a huge switch statement returning objects (17 of them) that implement the interface.  The created objects then call process like:

```
return xProcess.Process(requestDTO);
```

My problem is that I now need to change a few of these to pass in a second parameter like:

```
xProcess.Process(requestDTO, Id);
```

I'm looking for an elegant way to achieve this.

I have tried making the interface an abstract class like:

```
public abstract class IProcess
{

    public virtual IDTO Process(IDTO request)
    {
       return null;
    }

    public virtual IDTO Process(IDTO request, int Id)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This allows me to override the Process method in the created classes but I have a problem that IProcess is inherited by another interface, which is now obviously broken.

The legacy platform is huge and the test coverage is not great so I'm looking for a nice elegant solution with the minimum impact to the rest of the code base.  Perhaps, there is a pattern I'm overlooking?

Can anyone help please?  (examples would be great)

Thanks

David

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you not create a new interface that inherits from the existing one, like

```
public interface IProcess2 : IProcess
{
    IDTO Process(IDTO request, int Id);
}
```

Then change your classes to inherit from the new one.

This should stop any users of the existing IProcess from breaking.

Comment: Thanks.  I did play with this idea but the factory returns IProcess and I get an error saying that I can't convert IProcess to IProcess2.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, the factory would need changing too :)

Comment: @Justin - Absolutely :), was just about to add comment saying that's all I needed to do.  Excellent, thanks very much.

Comment: One thing - I need to create a Process(IDTO request) - not implemented stub when I inherit from IProcess2.  Is there anyway round this?

Comment: Yes, you could add an abstract base class in between.  So your base class inherits from IProcess2, and provides a not implemented stub for Process(IDTO request) and you then inherit all your factoried classes from the base class.